# How to fetch html data in python

Tags: python, html, flask

I have the following html code

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function processdata()
{
var un=document.getElementById('uname1');
alert("hI " + un.value);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" value=" " id="uname1">
<input type="button" name="sub" onclick="processdata();" value="Submit">

</body>

</html>
```

This html page is called in python/flask like this-

```
@app.route('/')
def getusername():
  return render_template('appHTML.html')
```

Now i want to fetch the value in the field 'uname' in a python variable.

Please tell me how to do it.
I am NOT using CGI.
I use flask instead.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using a `<form>`?

Comment: This is just a basic code to familiarize with the syntax of the asked question

Comment: HTML `<form>`s are a common means of receiving data from web-browsers, which is what I think you are asking how to do. `<input>` tags usually reside inside a `<form>`.

Comment: So `uname` is only pulled out by javascript... so the javascript would need to be modified to submit to an accepted url on the server

Comment: @MattH - Yes, thats precisely what i am looking for. All i find is answers related to CGI and urllib. there is some ambiguous stuff on "request" object which seems to be valid in my context but no syntax for the same

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you do not have a form tag - so the browser won't submit anything back to your server by default.

The way to get the browser to submit the form to your server is simply to wrap your inputs (both text and submit) in a `<form>` tag with an `action` attribute pointing at the URL where you will be accepting the response.

So your code would look like this (wrapping code left out):

```
<form action="/process-form" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" value=" " id="uname1">
<input type="button" name="sub" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You could use `method="get"` rather than `method="post"` if you wanted, but POST is generally what you are looking for. You will then set up your app to handle post requests at your endpoint:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("your_form_template.html")

@app.route("/process-form", methods=["POST"])
def process():
    username = request.form["uname"]
    return "Hello {}!".format(username)
```

If you want to be able to send the value back asynchronously to the server (so the entire page doesn't reload) then you can use Ajax to submit just the value to the server.  Your page will look the same - simply use JavaScript to prevent the form's submission and then submit an XHR request back to the server using the POST method.  (If this is all very confusing you may want to consider choosing a library to help abstract away some of the differences between browsers for you - jQuery is popular these days ... if a tad bit over-recommended.)

Comment: Thanks for your input...I tried doing exactly the way you suggested and this is the error i got on the webpage-
The method GET is not allowed for the requested URL.
Please help!

Comment: @DimpleShah - You should be hitting `localhost:5000/` not `localhost:5000/process-form` to load your page - if you are trying to reach the page via JavaScript you will need to set your method to POST on the XHR request.

Answer (score -2):

Here Some Example of Parser

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Start tag:", tag
        for attr in attrs:
            print "     attr:", attr
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "End tag  :", tag
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Data     :", data
    def handle_comment(self, data):
        print "Comment  :", data
    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        c = unichr(name2codepoint[name])
        print "Named ent:", c
    def handle_charref(self, name):
        if name.startswith('x'):
            c = unichr(int(name[1:], 16))
        else:
            c = unichr(int(name))
        print "Num ent  :", c
    def handle_decl(self, data):
        print "Decl     :", data

parser = MyHTMLParser()


parser.feed('<h1>Python</h1>')
Start tag: h1
Data     : Python
End tag  : h1
```

Comment: Please explain how this relates to the question.